# XmlException: Type not found

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, enums, datacontractserializer

I serialized a class with the code:

```
public void Save()
{
    string fichero = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + nombreJuego + ".dat";
    FileStream file = File.Create(fichero);
    DataContractSerializer bf = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(JuegoMesa));
    MemoryStream streamer = new MemoryStream();
    bf.WriteObject(streamer, this);
    streamer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    file.Write(streamer.GetBuffer(), 0, streamer.GetBuffer().Length);
    file.Close();
}
```

and deserialize it with:

```
public void Load()
{
    string fichero = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + nombreJuego + ".dat";
    Debug.Log(fichero);
    DataContractSerializer bf = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(JuegoMesa));
    try
    {
        JuegoMesa leido = null;
        object objeto;

        MemoryStream streamer = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(fichero));
        streamer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        objeto = bf.ReadObject(streamer);
        leido = (JuegoMesa)objeto;
        ActualizarListas(leido.listaListas);
        ActualizarPropiedades(leido.listaPropiedades);
        ActualizarRecursos(leido.listaRecursos);
        ActualizarComponentes(leido.listaComponentes);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        listaListas.Clear();
        listaPropiedades.Clear();
        listaRecursos.Limpiar();
        listaComponentes.Clear();
        Save();
    }
}
```

In reading the object gives me the exception:

> XmlException: Type not found; name: PropiedadTexto, namespace: http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatterDeserializer.GetTypeFromNamePair (System.String name, System.String ns)

The class has the following elements to serialize:

```
public string nombreJuego;
public List<TextosPredefinidos> listaListas;
public List<Propiedad> listaPropiedades;
public ListaRecursos listaRecursos;
public List<ListaRecursos> listaComponentes;
```

The

```
List<Propiedad>
```

is a object list of classes derived from the Propiedad class. By example the class with the error

```
[Serializable]
public class PropiedadTexto : Propiedad 
{
    public string textoDescriptivo;

    public PropiedadTexto() : base()
    {
    }

  ...
}
```

Does anyone know what can be the problem?

Apologize for my bad English.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the version of the code when the serializer was used and the de-serializer was used are different.  Somebody modified the one Classes and either added/deleted a property.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] that reproduces the problem?  We're more likely to be able to be able to help if we can test and debug the problem for ourselves;  see [ask] for more.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to create a minimal/complete/verifiable example, I found the solution. I still do not understand why it gives the error, but the solution is create a class derived from DataContractResolver and inform unknown types

```
class ResolverXml : DataContractResolver
{
    private XmlDictionary dictionary = new XmlDictionary();

    public ResolverXml()
    {
    }

    public override bool TryResolveType(Type dataContractType, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver, out XmlDictionaryString typeName, out XmlDictionaryString typeNamespace)
    {
        if (dataContractType == typeof(PropiedadTexto))
        {
            XmlDictionary dictionary = new XmlDictionary();
            typeName = dictionary.Add("PropiedadTexto");
            typeNamespace = dictionary.Add("JuegoMesa");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return knownTypeResolver.TryResolveType(dataContractType, declaredType, null, out typeName, out typeNamespace);
        }
    }

//    public override Type ResolveName(string typeName, string typeNamespace, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver)
    public override Type ResolveName(string typeName, string typeNamespace, Type type, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver)
    {
        if (typeName == "PropiedadTexto" && typeNamespace == "JuegoMesa")
        {
            return typeof(PropiedadTexto);
        }
        else
        {
            return knownTypeResolver.ResolveName(typeName, typeNamespace, type, null);
        }
    }
}
```

and it has to be indicated in the DataContractSerializer constructor

```
DataContractSerializer bf = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(PruebaXml), null, Int32.MaxValue, false, false, null, new ResolverXml());
```

But unity does not recognize the DataContractResolver class. The alternative used has been to inform the unknown types in the DataContractSerializer constructor.

```
private List<Type> tiposConocidos;
tiposConocidos.Add(typeof(PropiedadTexto));
tiposConocidos.Add(typeof(PropiedadEntero));
DataContractSerializer bf = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(JuegoMesa), tiposConocidos);
```